# Validity of Lebanese passport for entry into Turkey

Tags: passports, turkey, lebanese-citizens

My daughter who is Lebanese will travel to Antalya on the 4th of August. The validity of her passport is 171 days from her entry into Turkey. Is that sufficient for her to enter Turkish territory?

She has a reservation at a hotel and a return ticket for 5 days vacation. From the 4th of August until the 8th of August.

Answer (score 1):

[Timactic](https://www.skyteam.com/en/flights-and-destinations/visa-and-health/) (airline visa information database) says that Lebanese passports do not require a visa and are eligible for 90 days stay. The passport must be valid an additional 60 days. That would give your daughter 21 days margin. (I hope one of the Timactic experts here checks this.)